# Photos from SD Card showing up as Bitmap id code

Tags: android, bitmap, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, android-sdcard

I have code that seems to do two things: pull photos from an SD card directory, and add "placeholder" photos from a drawable resource to fill up a `GridView`. However, I only see what appears to be the `Bitmap` object hashcode (if that is the right term) for both operations. Any idea how to get the images to show instead?

[image]

**PhotoTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class PhotoTab extends Fragment{

    private GridView gridView;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> adapter;

    public PhotoTab(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, photoList);

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);

        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // read contents of SD card
        loadSDCard();

        // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
        for (int i = 0; i < (24 - photoList.size()); i++) {

            adapter.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            i++;
        }

        return v;
    }

    private void loadSDCard(){

        try {
            // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
            File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File cutePhotoDir = new File(baseDir, "/Documents/CutePhotos");
            // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
            files = cutePhotoDir.listFiles();


            for (File singleFile : files) {
                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                photoList.add(bitmap);

            }

            adapter.addAll(photoList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the layout you are using as row   `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, contains a `TextView`, and the `ArrayAdapter` is simply calling `toString()`, and the items of your dataset *assigning* the returned value to this `TextView`. To fix it, you have to subclass `ArrayAdapter` or `BaseAdapter` and override `getView`, to customize the aspect of your `GridView`'s items

Comment: Oh, so I need to change it to an `ImageView`? I did not have a custom adapter, so I wasn't sure how to populate my `GridView`.

Comment: you need a Custom Adapter

Comment: Ok, is a custom adapter possible with only one item? I always thought I needed at least 2 to make one, like a `TextView` and `ImageView` for instance.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, if it works I will mark your answer. But it will take me until tomorrow.